# Getting react-bootstrap to work in rails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have react and bootstrap in my rails application and so far they are working great independently. I would like to combine functionality by using react-bootstrap. I am following this tutorial to get things working: http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html.

I did the CommonJS part. where I did:

```
npm install react
npm install react-bootstrap
```

in the terminal.

I then went to my application.js file within my assets and added this code:
`Var Alert = require('react-bootstrap').Alert;`

In the console it errors on this line and it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not definedapplication.js?body=1:28 (anonymous function)`

How do I get require to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bundle your javascript using a tool like `webpack` or `browserify` before you pull it into your assets folder. I would recommend making a `react` folder or something in your project root and having one of these tools build the bundle into `app/assets/js` or wherever it is you have your assets.

Then add to the `assets:precompile` task and add a dev task accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer might help you to get your components work with less configuration, just using a gem! https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757447/4412754

Cheers!