# Configuring react-bootstrap with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to integrate React-bootstrap with my current Rails project. I am new to ReactJS, so I thought using the react-bootstrap lib would make things a bit easier. However, I find the configuration very hard. There is supposedly a gem for this, but it throws an error of 'Permission denied' once the instructions on the README are followed. I tried a snipped from the react-bootstrap web site, which works without the react-bootstrap syntax. However, all the solutions I have tried involing Bower, npm, rails-assets gem, etc., don't make the react-bootstrap syntax render. This is my Button.js.jsx file which won't render to my home page:

```
var button = ReactBootstrap.Button({
  bsStyle: "success",
  bsSize: "large",
  children: "Register"
});

React.render(button, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Tips and suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: How are you bringing ReactBootstrap into scope? Are you using CommonJS? Or are you using the asset pipeline and requiring react-bootstrap via sprockets?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today of integrating the react-bootstrap package into my RoR application, so I found this gem: https://github.com/mariopeixoto/react-bootstrap-rails which basically puts all react bootstrap components at your disposal by just accessing a global variable ReactBootstrap.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have bootstrap.min.css included in your HTML file.

**Something else to keep in mind is that facebook admits to this being in development.**

The project is under active development, and APIs will change. Check out the 1.0.0 Roadmap and Contributing Guidelines to see where you can help out. Prior to the 1.0.0 release, breaking changes should result in a Minor version bump.

Make sure that you follow these steps (http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) for however you are including the files

I personally chose this way and it created the elements fine for me.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/<react-version>/react.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/react-bootstrap-bower/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the aforementioned [gem](https://github.com/mariopeixoto/react-bootstrap-rails), and including

```
//= require react_bootstrap
```

in application.js, I was able to get the following code to render without errors.

```
var button = ReactBootstrap.Button;

ReactDOM.render(<button 
    bsStyle="success"
    bsSize="large"
    children="Register"/>,
  document.getElementById("content"));
```

Comment: I don't think, this gem is being maintained